# PHP MySQL ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1

Tags: php, mysql

i have a script to show the most watched movie. This information is from a MySQL Database.

This code works:

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT title, time, filename, imageurl, ms, bekeken, genres FROM movies ORDER BY bekeken 
DESC LIMIT 1";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
//
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
            echo '<div class="right-content">
        <div class="popular">
            <h3>Populairste film</h3>
            <p>Meest bekeken film!</p>
            <div class="clear"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid1">
                    <h3>' . $row["title"] . '</h3>
                    <a href="player.php?file=' . $row["filename"] . '&ms=' . $row["ms"] . '"><img src="' . $row["imageurl"] . '" title="' . $row["title"] . '"  height="260" width="200"/></a>
                    <div class="time1">
                        <span>' . $row["time"] . '</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="grid-info">

                        <div class="video-watch">
                            <a href="#">Kijk nu!</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear"> </div>
                        <div class="lables">
                            <p>Genre:<a href="genres.php?g=">' . $row["genre"] . '</a></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>';
}
}
?>
```

The problem:

When the variable "bekeken" is more than 10, it automatically selects the one less than 10 as most watched.

It does not properly select the one where "bekeken" is the highest number.

It works perfectly if all the numbers in the database row "numbers" are less than 10.

How can i fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the mysql create code? `SHOW CREATE TABLE movies`;

Comment: Is the bekeken column a number or a string?

Comment: you need to convert bekeken to numbers as stated in the answer bellow.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the problem is that `bekeken` is not stored as a number, but as a string.  You can convert it to a number for the sorting:

```
SELECT title, time, filename, imageurl, ms, bekeken, genres
FROM movies
ORDER BY (bekeken + 0) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Better to alter the table, so mysql can use the index for sorting.